# Install Z3 in Windows

Tags: z3

I did download the file  Z3 4.3.0 for Windows (64 bits) that is on site: http://z3.codeplex.com/releases.

When I try to run the file z3.exe which is in the bin folder. Prompt appears and disappears immediately. I needed to know how to run a file written in z3 through z3.exe file.

How can I do this? Or what is the best option to run z3 through Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z3.exe` is a command line tool. To execute a SMT-LIB 2.0 file called `file.smt2`, you should execute the following command in the Command Prompt.

```
 z3 file.smt2
```

If the directory containing `z3.exe` is not in your `PATH` environment variable, you will have to include the directory in the command above.

BTW, Z3 has not graphical user interface or environment. It is essentially a library for automated reasoning. `z3.exe` is a simple executable built using this library that allows us execute commands stored in a file.

You can also play with Z3 using the web interface available at [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/).
At rise4fun, we have a [SMT-LIB](http://rise4fun.com/Z3) front-end, and a [Python](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py) based one.
Both of them have interactive tutorials.

Here are some useful resources to learn about SMT:

- [Z3 tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide)
- [Tutorial on SMT-LIB](http://www.grammatech.com/resources/smt/SMTLIBTutorial.pdf)
- [Article describing SMT applications](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1995394)
- [SMT-Lib benchmarks](http://www.smtlib.org/)
- Stackoverflow: you can search Z3 related question by including `[z3]` in the search box.

Z3 has APIs for several programming languages: C, C++, .Net, Python and OCaml.
In the next release, we will also provide support for Java.
You can already play with the Java by using one of the nightly builds.
Go [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/precompiled.html) for more information about Z3 nightly builds.
The nightly builds contain a Java example application using the Z3 API.

Comment: So at this moment it is still not possible to use with java?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to use the nightly build. It is not an official release, but a preview. The link I included above explains it. There are several people already using the Java API and the nightly builds.